# Passing variables in child_window pywinauto

Tags: python, pywinauto

Is it possible to use variable name as argument in the child_window object when using pywinauto?

Instead of below

```
app.Dialog.child_window(title='Position',class_name='RibbonPageHeaderControl').select()
```

when I use tabName = 'Position'

```
app.Dialog.child_window("title='"+tabName+"'",class_name='RibbonPageHeaderControl').select()
```

I get error:

```
tabSel.selectSubTab('Position','Depository Details')
  File "C:/myCode/AutomationSuites/CCMP/Functions\Tab.py", line 21, in selectSubTab
    Tab.selectTab(app,tabName)
  File "C:/myCode/AutomationSuites/CCMP/Functions\Tab.py", line 17, in selectTab



app.Dialog.child_window("title='"+tabName+"'",class_name='RibbonPageHeaderControl').select()
TypeError: child_window() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this using:

```
app.Dialog.child_window(title=""+tabName+"",class_name='RibbonPageHeaderControl').select()
```